# MS Exchange Calendar Filter

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, calendar

I would like to create a server-side Exchange calendar that is:

- A combination of a group of people's calendars (e.g., "Marketing Department Members")
- Filtered only to show those items marked "Out of Office"

Are there some ideas out there for programming Exchange server-side like this or using a package that's already implemented this?

The purpose is to create group calendars that everyone can view, showing who's out of the office in a department.

I know this can be done in Outlook with combined views and filtering, but it doesn't make any sense to create one or more of these on each and every user's PC in our organization.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that you can do this server-side.  Your best bet is to create a shared account calendar or a public folder calendar for people to add their Out-of-Office time.  (Yes, people will gripe, but I think you can copy/paste into another calendar)

Comment: This is how I have been doing it.

Comment: Ah, yes, this is how most people are doing it. Unfortunately, it's also why most departments are out of sync, which is the problem I'm trying to solve. Thanks.

Comment: Bravo to you for trying!  If you figure it out, tell the world!